How to know protomter position in the chromosome?
Could you tell me how to find the promoter position of a gene in the chromosome?
Recently I did ATAC-seq expriment and got the result, showing that the peaks related to some genes is assigned to "promoter". The result gives the chromosome position of the peak but I am curious about whether the promoters of these genes really overlap the peak position. For example, a peak in chromosome 1 (ref genome: mm39; position: 149975557~149975957) is assigned to the gene "Ptgs2", and the annotation is "Promoter (<=1kb)". So where can I get the precise coordination of the promoter for "Ptgs2"? I tried UCSC, Ensembl, or NCBI's Genome Data Viewer but cannot find the promoter information of the gene.
Thank you！

Does this help? https://epd.expasy.org/epd/cgi-bin/get_doc?db=mmEpdNew&format=genome&entry=Ptgs2_1 Also, how exactly are you defining the "start" and "end" positions of a promoter? I admit I haven't worked on this sort of thing much, but I believe they're kind of "fuzzy", promoters.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
